# Trouble shooting Laravel too many connections

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I've created a rather simple multi-tenant application using separate schemas in a Postgresql database. I keep a `public` schema, which only a few model use and then the rest of my models use the `tenant.` I determine the Client from the subdomain through a middleware then, call the following function on my Client model to set the credentials for the connection.

```
public function logInAsClient()
{
    $settings = $this->settings;

    // set tenant db
    config([
        'client' => $settings,
        'client.id' => $this->id,
        'database.connections.tenant.schema' => $this->schema,
        'schema' => $this->schema,
        'domain' => $this->domain,
    ]);

    DB::disconnect('tenant');
    DB::reconnect('tenant');

    return true;
}
```

It's working great in normal functions, but I have several tasks which require me to queue up hundreds of jobs at a time. Since they are all running on the same app, I pass the `client_id` to each job and then at the start of the handle run:

```
Client::find($this->client_id)->logInAsClient();
```

However, when running this code I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

I don't there there is any other part of my app where I am connecting or reconnecting to databases so I'm not sure where else this issue might be coming from. If there are any hints on how to debug an issue like this it would be greatly appreciated.